# Can't launch the selenium remote driver in docker container

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to dockerize my crawler with using selenium and I use the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.1.1-20220121
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.1.1-20220121
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

  crawler:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - chrome
```

After that, I am trying to open web browser session executing the following python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME 
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=cap)
```

I am not sure why it will trigger the following MaxRetryError:

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='selenium-hub', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f569421cdd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I have done some research and I found that some people faced the same problem but their solution are not workable for me (eg. [python jupyter notebook in docker container connection to selenium/standalone-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217645/python-jupyter-notebook-in-docker-container-connection-to-selenium-standalone-ch)). Also I think I am using the same network since I am using the docker compose to create the image with both my crawler, selenium-hub and chrome and contain it together.

May I know how do I fix this problem? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Try to follow selenium 4 docker compose config example https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/4.1.1-20220121/docker-compose-v3.yml. I see you have differences.

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka This is the exact yaml file that I tried at the beginning. Basically I just add my crawler part in the yaml file that you posted but not work too. Anyways, I will try it once again. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Try to put delay to your crawler code. Say 10 seconds. `depends_on` in your compose file does not mean it will wait for service to be completely ready.